# How to unit test attributes with MsTest using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, attributes, mstest

How to test the presence of Class Attributes and Method Attributes with MsTest using C#?

Comment: This seems like overkill. You can just inspect the source code.

Comment: Actually this sort of thing is quite good for catching refactoring blunders. Making sure that code that relies on the attributes is well tested (and gives decent error messages) is also important.

Comment: @chibacity: But behavior that depends on the attributes is implicitly testing the existence of the attributes. I don't see what value the additional tests are adding.

Comment: @Jason Tests may only be testing specimen cases, they do not necessarily test all classes that opt into the attribute convention as this is not the focus of the test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[C# Extension method for checking attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476757/c-extension-method-for-checking-attributes/3477106#3477106)

```
public static bool HasAttribute<TAttribute>(this MemberInfo member) 
    where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    var attributes = 
        member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true);

    return attributes.Length > 0;
}
```

Comment: spot on and can be complemented into my answer above.  I might just do this.  Much more elegant.

Comment: Or you could implement it with `System.Linq` and use .Any()

Answer (score 4):

Use reflection, for example here is one in nunit + c#, which be easily adapted to MsTest.

```
[Test]
public void AllOurPocosNeedToBeSerializable()
{
  Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (PutInPocoElementHere));
  int failingTypes = 0;
  foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
  {
    if(type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Entity)))
    {
       if (!(type.HasAttribute<SerializableAttribute>())) failingTypes++;
       Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
       //whole test would be more concise with an assert within loop but my way
       //you get all failing types printed with one run of the test.
    }
  }
  Assert.That(failingTypes, Is.EqualTo(0), string.Format("Look at console output 
     for other types that need to be serializable. {0} in total ", failingTypes));
}

//refer to Robert's answer below for improved attribute check, HasAttribute
```

Comment: With a bit of work, I bet you could make `IsTypeSerializable` a generic method that can handle any attribute.

Comment: @Robert, absolutely, it might also make read better as an extension on System.Type, which I may include for the heck of it

Comment: @Robert, had a little toy with that and it's quite doable but think it would only clutter answer above.  My answer is very much fixed with testing in mind, having the failing types written to the console.  The extension method might have a signature like: public static bool IsTypeSerializeable(this System.Type type, System.Type checkType)  // though you might want to just have an attribute in as second parameter, needs a little more work which I'd only do if it was called for. okay, i'll put it in ;)

Comment: Did a little Googling, and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476757/c-extension-method-for-checking-attributes

Comment: @robert nice one, was about to add more to answer but just +1 your link instead, as I'm about to point out to @Thomas, what I like about my test (and others I haven't put here) is that with one test run you get all failing entity outputted to console, saving multiple re-runs of test for each failing entity

Answer (score 1):

Write yourself two helper functions (using reflection) along these lines:

```
public static bool HasAttribute(TypeInfo info, Type attributeType)
public static bool HasAttribute(TypeInfo info, string methodName, Type attributeType)
```

Then you can write tests like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(HasAttribute(myType, expectedAttribute));
```

This way you don't need to use if/else/foreach or other logic in your test methods. Thus they become far more clear and readable.

HTH
Thomas

Comment: you have a point but my test (and others I haven't put here) is that with one test run you get all failing entity outputted to console, saving multiple re-runs of test for each failing entity, as Robert has give, there are more elegant ways still.